# How to set environment variable for ant

Tags: java, cordova, ant

I am trying to build my first android app using phonegap and for that i need jdk environment,node.js,ant.
And I am able to install jdk but for Apache ant I have tried many forum and tutorials for setting the path but not able to succeeded on this.

I set my varialbe like this....
Variable Name :- ANT_HOME
Variable Value:- C:\JAVA\ant\bin

Variable Name :- JAVA_HOME
Variable Value:- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\bin\

But still i am getting "unalbe to locate tools.jar. Expected to find in C:\ProgramFiles\java\jre7\lib\tools.jar
BuildFile: build.xml doest not exists.
Build Failed.

**PLEASE HELP ME OUT FROM THIS ANONYMOUS TROUBLES..**

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` should be the JDK installation directory (in your case `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\`. Then you add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the path.

For java, see [Update the PATH Environment Variable (Microsoft Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

You can follow a similar procedure to add `ANT_HOME` to your path. `ANT_HOME` should be `C:\JAVA\ant` and then you add `%ANT_HOME%\bin` to the path.

If `echo %PATH%` shows the correct values for both ant and java then you need to check your Cordova configuration as it appears your configuration is pointing to a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) instead of a Java Development Kit (JDK).

Answer (score 0):

See [**HERE**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#setup) for `Ant, jdk, tools.jar` related instructions.

- for `Ant`:

  `ANT_HOME` set to `C:\JAVA\ant` and add `;%ANT_HOME%\bin` to the `PATH` variable
- for `JDK`:

  `JAVA_HOME` set to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\"` (**with the quotes** *if you have space(s) in your file path*) and add `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your `PATH` variable.
- close any command-prompt window(s) that were open prior to the changes above. Only command windows opened after the changes will have the updated environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 different ways:

***1: From Command Prompt.***
C:>set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Ant Files\apache-ant-1.10.5

C:>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

C:>set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

C:> ant -version

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on July 10 2018

***2: By setting environment variables.***

Right click on **This PC > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > User variables > New > Variable name:**ANT_HOME & for **Variable value:**C:\Program Files\Ant Files\apache-ant-1.10.5 > **OK**.

Now goto **System variables** to add bin path. **System variables** > double click on **Path** >**New** > C:\Program Files\Ant Files\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin >**New** >C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin>**OK**.

Now lets check whether it is installed correctly or not.

goto Command Prompt > and type ant -version.

C:> ant -version

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on July 10 2018

That's it. Let me know if still getting any difficulties.